# Proof of a congruence relation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let n∈N, and let a,b∈Z. Suppose that a≡b (mod n). Prove that n|a if and only if n|b.

As can be proceed?

Comment: $n\mid a\iff a\equiv 0\pmod {\! n}$. Since $a\equiv b$, we must have $a\equiv 0\iff b\equiv 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a biconditional statement, you must prove the statement in both directions.

- **If n | a**:

$a - b = nk$ for some integer k (by hypothesis)

$a = qn$ for some integer q (by definition of divisibility)

$b = a - kn = nq - nk = n(q-k)$

Thus n divides b.

- **If n | b**:

$a - b = nk$ for some integer k (by hypothesis)

$b = np$ for some integer p (by definition of divisibility)

$a = nk + b = nk + np = n(k+p)$

Thus n divides a.

This ends the proof.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: You have: $a-b = kn, a = mn \to b = (b-a)+a = -kn+mn = (m-k)n$